# size of the jbutton

Tags: java

How do i make a button smaller? It covers up the whole background. I want to make it smaller. I dont understand why setbounds do not work. size 35,120, 90 ,60

```
import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import static java.lang.System.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;

    public class GameFrame
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {


            JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("PoopMan");
            gameFrame.setSize(900,800);
            background1.setBounds(0,0,900,800);
            gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gameFrame.setResizable(false);
            gameFrame.setVisible(true);
            gameFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);



             JButton button1 = new JButton("CONTROLS");
             button1.setBounds(35, 120, 90, 60);
            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) e.getSource(), "CONTROLS ARE ....");
          }
        });


    gameFrame.add(button1);
```

Comment: try gameFrame.getContentPane().add(button1);

Comment: @Ryan `JFrame`'s add function is redirected to the content pane already: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't even compile:

```
gameFrame().add(button1);
```

gameFrame is a reference, not a function. It should be:

```
gameFrame.add(button1);
```

Also you should do this **before** you set the frame visible to true.

Here is the complete solution:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class GameFrame
{

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("PoopMan");
                gameFrame.setSize(900,800);
                gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                gameFrame.setResizable(false);
                //gameFrame.setVisible(true);
                gameFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);

                JButton button1 = new JButton("CONTROLS");
                button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) e.getSource(), "CONTROLS ARE ....");
                                }
                                });


                gameFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
                gameFrame.add(button1);
                gameFrame.setVisible(true);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you even compiled it.
needed changes:

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
gameFrame().add(button1);
```

change to:

```
gameFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
gameFrame.add(button1);
```